# how to use ajax jquery for a form message letting the error to show?

Tags: php, jquery

Im new to the ajax jquery i read about it and mess around with the codes but im still not understanding on some stuff , Im trying to creating a message form, i want  my script in php processes the message and when theirs a error, i want the error to show on the same page of the form and i also dont want  the page to refresh when click submit.

here what i got , i know its not a lot im still trying to understand on how to work with ajax jquery

```
<script>
$.post("message/sendm.php", {message:"#message" } );

</script>
  <div id="send"  style="color:#000" class="reveal-modal">

       <form name="message" method="post" style="background:#999">
<table>
<tr><td>To:<?php echo $user ?></td></tr>  
<tr><td>Message:<textarea style="resize:none"  id="message"name="text" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea></td></tr>  
<tr><td><input name="message" type="submit" value="Send!"></td></tr>  
</form> 
     </table>
```

i know its not a lot im still trying to understand on how to work with ajax jquery and if anyone knows a good book to learn ajax jquery please let me know. I already try the [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) website its not really useful it doesnt explain everything, like it doesnt explain on how to send $_Post to the php page to process any errors and how to show them on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to make ajax calls to a server. A method I like to use is:

```
$("#form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //this stops the default form action
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', //this is how you specify post or get
        url: 'myform.php', //this is where your server file for processing the form goes
        data: $('#form').serialize(); //serialize all the data from the form
        success: function (data) {
                 $('#alerts').html(data)//fills the element with the id of alerts with whatever is returned from the php page.
        }
    });
});
```

Then you just have to create a page on your server for processing the information (in my example it would be myform.php. Anything you output from the php page (i.e. using echo) will show up in the element with the id alerts.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: alright thanks ,, the thing i dont understand #form does it grab every $_post in the form than sends it to the server to process it? or only where id is located at?. `<form id="form"></form>` or `<input id="form"> ` or both ways work?

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid using native HTML form submission if your going for a Web 2.0 feel.  Rather, create a button using the .button function in jquery.  On click (.onclick), serialize the form and post it to your backend using the .ajax function in jquery.  You can handle the response by using the .done function or the success option (within the Ajax function)